# Query de registros não similares

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela onde faço o cruzamento de dados de permuta de alguns profissionais, Por exemplo, o prof A tem em comum a permuta com o prof F, logo F tem com o A também. Mas no relatório de permutas eu não gostaria que mostrasse F com A, somente A com F, porque a informação em si é a mesma coisa na pratica, embora no banco sejam registros diferentes.

Como eu faço um SQL que atenda essa minha condição?

Exemplo, Fábio trabalha no na UBS Centro e quer mudar para a UBS Anchieta, Anderson trabalha na UBS Anchieta e quer mudar para a UBS Centro. Os dois se cadastram no Sistema de Permuta, no banco existem os dois registros gravados, 
nome     / origem      / opção
Fábio     UBS Centro     UBS Anchieta
Anderson  UBS Anchieta   UBS Centro

No relatório aparece:
Fábio quer permutar com Anderson
Anderson quer permutar com Fábio

Essa duplicidade no relatório não é necessária.

[image: tabela]

Comment: Se são a mesma coisa, deveriam existir registros distintos?

Comment: Woss, ficou meio confuso, mas atualizei a pergunta. Obrigado man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também não entendi o motivo como o Woss disse.

Mas em todo caso, um exemplo de como fazer:

*(pode haver outras formas, até mais simples)*

*Considerando*

- Tabela = tab
- PK = id
- Coluna1 = c1
- Coluna2 = c2

---

```
 select *
 from tab
 where id in (
 select
 (case when (t1.id < t2.id or t2.id is null) then t1.id else null end) c
 from tab t1
 left join tab t2 on t2.c1 = t1.c2 and t2.c2 = t1.c1
 )
 group by c1, c2
 order by id
```

---

Exemplo no [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4df86/1)

Comment: RBZ, obrigado pela força, acho que é esse o caminho, porém dê uma olhada no http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f6926/1, na primeira linha A-B e ultima linha B-A, nesse caso sairia o B-A, A-B e B-A nesse caso especifico são a mesma coisa...

Comment: @FábioMartins Acho que pegou um link errado. Eu atualizei a resposta depois. Veja novamente.

Comment: Veja que o select que está na resposta, já não é mais esse do link que passou acima, e sim: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4df86/1

Comment: obrigado man, funcionou. Deus abençoe.

Comment: no caso de 3 colunas, A-B-C, C-B-A, nessa lógica é possível fazer também?

Comment: Sim... Aumentaria 1 `join` e várias outras condições `case`.

Answer (score 1):

Para duas colunas,

```
(select q.A, q.B, q.id_da_materia_ou_algo_em_comum_entre_A_e_B
 from
    (select A, B, id_da_materia_ou_algo_em_comum_entre_A_e_B
     from tabela

     intersect

     select B, A, id_da_materia_ou_algo_em_comum_entre_A_e_B
     from tabela) q
where q.A < q.B)

union

(select A, B, id_da_materia_ou_algo_em_comum_entre_A_e_B
from tabela

except

select B, A, id_da_materia_ou_algo_em_comum_entre_A_e_B
from tabela)
```

Para mais de duas colunas, a quantidade de intersects/excepts é igual ao fatorial do número de colunas,

```
(select q.A, q.B, q.C, q.emcomum
from 
    (select A, B, C, emcomum
     from tabela
     intersect
     select A, C, B, emcomum
     from tabela
     intersect
     select C, A, B, emcomum
     from tabela
     intersect
     select C, B, A, emcomum
     from tabela
     intersect
     select B, C, A, emcomum
     from tabela
     intersect
     select B, A, C, emcomum
     from tabela) q
where q.A < q.B and q.B < q.C)

union

(select A, B, C, emcomum
 from tabela
 except
 select B, A, C, emcomum
 from tabela
 except
 select B, C, A, emcomum
 from tabela
 except
 select C, B, A, emcomum
 from tabela
 except
 select C, A, B, emcomum
 from tabela
 except
 select A, C, B, emcomum
 from tabela)
```

Comment: funcionou com a sua reposta também. Obrigado :)